# ASP.NET Stopwatch Remaining at 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, stopwatch

So, as part of an assignment I am trying to roughly calculate the time taken for a transaction to be reviewed and completed in an ASP.NET Web Forms project using CSharp.

In my ASPX page, I am showing the details of the objects in the cart.
And there is a button which confirms the checkout and completes it.

What I need to calculate is the time since the page loaded, till the checkout was confirmed.

Here there are two events:  `page_load` and `checkoutbutton_click`

So in the code behind file I am

```
public partial class CheckoutReview : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sw.Start();
        //... code
    }

    protected void checkoutbutton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //...code
       sw.Stop();
       // in the database i am then storing the elapsedMilliSeconds of the stopwatch
    }
```

The problem however is that with this code the elapsed time is remained 0 all the time.
If I put the same stopwatch however in the `checkoutbutton_click()` the `stopwatch` works fine.

Can someone kindly explain what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time the page is posted back to the server, a new instance of the class `CheckoutReview` is being created... so what you're seeing is the time between the creation of the class **on the post-back** and the event handler.

You have to remember that each request to the server (whether it's the original page request, or a post-back) is an individual call to the server.  Things like `Session` and `ViewState` exist to allow you use data between those requests.

I would recommend you store the current time in the `ViewState` of the page on the **initial** load, and then check the `TimeSpan` difference in the event handler...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
    // Only store on first visit to the page
    ViewState["pageLoadTime"] = DateTime.Now;
  }
}

protected void checkoutbutton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now - (DateTime)ViewState["pageLoadTime"];
}
```

Comment: got it and works fine.  so viewstate refers to the time the page is being seen and is destroyed when the page is left ?  Thanks for the information.  I will research about this, because I am just trying out and learning by myself here.

Comment: Good, it's really important to understand the ASP.NET [page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), the better you understand it, the less likely you are to get these issues.  The `ViewState` exists for the life of the page, and is hidden as part of the page within the `__VIEWSTATE` hidden control.  I think it's safer than `Session` as it only exists within the page, and isn't lost if IIS recycles between page requests

Comment: The `ViewState` also holds all the information for server-side controls... it's why you can set `<asp:Literal>` for instance, and it will still be set on a post-back